# Django Error ImportError at / cannot import name models

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm not experiencing this issue when I'm developing but when I deploy to apache 2.2 on centos 6 I keep getting this error:

```
ImportError at /
no module named models
Request Method: GET
Django Version: 1.6.5
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
cannot import name models
Exception Location: /var/www/quiz_app/proj/builder/views/my_quizzes.py in <module>,                line 5
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.6.6
Python Path:    
['/var/www/quiz_app/proj/builder',
'/var/www/quiz_app/proj',
'/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-5.3-py2.6.egg',
'/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.6.egg',
'/usr/lib64/python26.zip',
'/usr/lib64/python2.6',
'/usr/lib64/python2.6/plat-linux2',
'/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-tk',
'/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-old',
'/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload',
'/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages',
'/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages']
```

I'm using Django 1.6.5 and python 2.6 I'm really stuck on this one, any help would be very appreciated! If you need any additional info please let me know.

The file it is giving the error on is a view called my_quizzes.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required  
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse, HttpResponseNotFound
from django.shortcuts import render
from builder import models as b
```

My httpd.conf file looks like this:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/quiz_app/proj/quiz/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/quiz_app/proj/

<Directory /var/www/quiz_app/proj/\>
  <Files wsgi.py>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
  </Files>
</Directory>
```

settings.py installed apps looks like

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'homepage',
'administration',
'exam',
'builder',
)
```

If it's helpful to anyone here is the relevant Tree Structure

```
|proj
|-builder
 |-__init__.py
 |-models.py
 |-views
  |-__init__.py
  |-my_quizzes.py (this is where the import error is occurring)
```

Comment: Make sure to check your settings file to ensure that the app is imported correctly. I would also double check your imports to make sure you haven't made a typo in your import path.

Comment: Usually caused by circular module imports in your code.

Comment: Even if I'm not having this problem in dev? How would I check for that?

Comment: The problem with the Django development server is that it causes all sorts of side effects when loading the Django management commands. This causes changes to the order in which things are loaded in your code and often can obscure import order issues that you will encounter in a production grade WSGI server. Quite out of date now so likely shouldn't be used, but http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2010/03/improved-wsgi-script-for-use-with.html explains the issue.

Comment: Looking at this more, it seems like It just isn't finding the models file to import, has no one else encountered this issue? I can not find away around it, and have even tried deploying multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out my issue was purely a path issue. I still don't fully understand why, and if someone wants to add more details I'd be happy to add them here.

I was trying to import the models file for the app in a view that was a folder. In this case the app was called builder. So when I called form builder import models as b. I was getting an import error. To fix this I changed it to from .. import models as b.

The weird thing is I could import other apps models (that have the same file organization) simply using from administration import models as a. Just views within the app could not directly import the models file.

Thanks for all those who tried to help! Graham's comments led me in the right direction to figure out what was going on here.